# Difficulty in building .install file of my module in drupal

Tags: drupal, installation, hook

I am trying to build my own module but getting problem in using hook menu  in .install file. can someone illustrate the use of hook in .install file?

Answer (score 1):

HOOK_menu should go in .module files, not .install files.
Read [Writing .install files (Drupal 7.x)](https://www.drupal.org/node/876250)